# Clarification on how Arguments,Parameters, and types work

Tags: c#, terminology

So I'm new to code and I just want to make sure this is correct because for the most part im self-taught and I don't want to teach myself the wrong terminology.

Type - is the type of variable

example: int john = 5;

int = type

Parameter - refers to the name of the variable

example: int john = 5;

john = parameter

Argument - refers to the value bound to the variable

example: int john = 5;

5 = Argument

Is this correct if not may I please get some guidance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`john` is a **variable** of `int` **type** and **value** 5.

If you call a function or method that accepts an int parameter, john can be its argument:
Below, v is a paramenter of SetPersonAge method:

```
public void SetPersonAge(int v) {
  person.age = v;
}
```

So you can pass john as an argument:

```
SetPersonAge(john);
```

john is the first (and only) argument of this method call.

Answer (score 4):

The Functions or Methods defines the parameters, and the calling code that passes values to these Parameters are called arguments.

In other words; parameters are the variables which are part of Method or Function’s signature. Arguments are expression or real values when calling the method.

In Russian (and probably Italian) "parameters" are called "formal parameters", while "arguments" are called "actual parameters".

Answer (score 0):

The type you got perfectly right.

Honestly I am not so sure what the difference (if any) between Argument and Parameter is. I heard them used interchangibly. Most often when refering to the *type* or *value* of a parameter/argument.

So it could be one of those differences you never run into in practice. The kind of distinction only higher computer science bothers with. Or even no distinction at all.